django печать xls документа в 1 клик в браузере
Как можно реализовать быструю печать xls таблицы. Под словом быструю я имею ввиду кликаем по кнопке. идет генерация xls файла, он скачивается, затем его открываем, затем выбираем печать, печатаем. Хотелось бы упростить процесс - до кликаем и открывается окно печати документа..
Нашел решение библиотека Spire.XLS - конвертируем xls -> pdf  и сразу печатаем в браузере, пример:
pip install Spire.XLS
from spire.xls import *
from spire.xls.common import *

workbook = Workbook()

# Load a XLS or XLSX document
workbook.LoadFromFile("sample.xlsx")

# Iterate through the worksheets in the workbook
for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
    # Get the PageSetup object
    pageSetup = sheet.PageSetup

    # Set page margins
    pageSetup.TopMargin = 0.3
    pageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.3
    pageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.3
    pageSetup.RightMargin = 0.3

# Set worksheet to fit to page when converting
workbook.ConverterSetting.SheetFitToPage = True

# Convert to PDF file
workbook.SaveToFile("ToPdf.pdf", FileFormat.PDF)
workbook.Dispose()

Работает, но возник нюанс, эта библиотека похоже платная. огромная красная надпись вылезает на всех страницах pdf
Evaluation Warning The document was created with Spire.XLS for Python
и вопрос, будет ли она работать на linux ?
Вообщем как еще можно реализовать задачу печать xls файла в 1 клик

Отрендерить свой xls-файл наверно можно и через либреофис какой-нибудь

Путь через невидимый iframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023729/i-want-to-print-another-document-using-a-button-in-html

вызов окна печати НЕ проблема. проблема чтобы распечатать xls в браузере, какой утилитой его преобразовать? подскажите либреофис как можно преобразовать? это надо офис ставить на сервер? или какая то утилита есть?
